# Node.js - Cannot read property 'isDirectory' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, web

I tried to run this small node test app but when I try to use the stat method from the fs module, it keeps on throwing the same error as - cannot read property 'isDirectory' of undefined

```
var http = require("http");
var fileSys = require("fs");

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    if(req.statusCode != 404) {
        fileSys.readdir("templates", function(error, folders) {
            if(!error) {
                for (var i in folders) {
                    fileSys.stat(folders[i], function(error, stats) {
                        if(!error) {
                           res.writeHead("200", {"Content-type": "text/plain"});
                           res.end(stats.isDirectory());
                        } else {
                            console.log(error);
                            return;
                        }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                console.log(error);
                return;
            }
        });
    }
}).listen(8080);


console.log("Server started.......");
console.log("Server running on  loopback:8080 ;)");
```

then I ran the code twice with and without admin privileges but the problem still persists and the error shows up

Comment: Does your `stats` variable have **any** properties?  What does it print whenever you `util.inspect()` it?  [fs.Stats](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats)

Comment: The problem is your synchronous for loop. However, you get a list of files which you call folders. For every file you check the properties of the first file only and then attempt to respond despite the fact that the for loop has already completed by the time you start the second one. What exacty are you trying to do?

Comment: @chriskelly Well, I've got this 'templates' folder and this template folder is going to have several themes and each theme is denoted by their distinct folder. I'm trying to iterate through all the FOLDERS/DIRECTORIES in the templates folder. I will only display a list of all the directories in the templates folder and skip the ones which appear to be files.

Comment: @chriskelly I changed the for loop and I'm now incrementing the var i. But now I get something like this: { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'default'] errno: -2, code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'stat', path: 'default' }
The templates folder now has got another folder called default.

Comment: Problem is that anything you do with files takes time and node does not wait. The for loop is over before it's run fs.stat() on the first file/folder. You need to gather the results in an array and keep a track of the counter. When the counter reachs zero resolve your request. You could make life easier by downloading a module to recursively search your top-level directory. e.g. npm install recursive-readdir and then prune the results synchronously without worrying about i/o

Comment: ENOENT means no file or folder and it probably means you didn't concatenate path and file back together correctly (has happened me often). I would suggest using: var path = require('path'); and in your code console.log(path.resolve(your_filename)); to make sure those files are real

Comment: @chriskelly thanx. It worked finally

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your path at

```
fileSys.stat(folders[i], function(error, stats)
```

`folders[i]` may not be a real path, you should use its path rather than its fileName. Such as "./uploads/" + fileName.

Comment: It is noteworthy that we can add extra "/" in your path, but it will has error when lack of "/", For example, we use "./uploads/" ,not "./uploads".